# How to return cached actionresult from an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Controller.ViewData["currentuser"] == null)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HomeController().IndexCache();
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}

[OutputCache(Duration=3600)]
public ActionResult IndexCache()
{
    return view()
}
```

This is not working. I want to return cached if user is not logged-in. This is not final code.

I need to check the action = "index" and controller = "home" before serve them cached Index().

When I create controllers' the new instance is not cached.
Can someone tell me how I can return cached index in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect to action like

```
filterContext.Result =  new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "controller", "Home" },
                    { "action", "IndexCache" });
```

Instead of making a function call `new HomeController().IndexCache();`

Comment: Thanks Satpal for this but I am looking for a solution without changing the url